# Declaring vector size in a class

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, visual-studio-2013

I am supposed to write a program that simulates a dice(6 faced) roll 6000 times and stores the results in a vector. For example if the dice roll returns 1, I would do something like frequency.at(0)++. Since the size of the vector is gonna be fixed, and I would also need to able to access each element freely, I was wondering if there was anyway to declare the size of the vector using a default constructor or something. This is what I currently have but I get a "too many arguments in function call" and "expression must have class type" error. Maybe what I'm trying to do is not possible, I don't know, but just looking for some help. Thanks.

My header file:

```
#ifndef AHISTOGRAM_H
#define AHISTOGRAM_H


class aHistogram
{
public:
    aHistogram();
    ~aHistogram();
    void update(int face);
    void display(int maxLengthOfLine);
    void clear() const;
    int count(int face);
private:
    vector<int> numRolls();
    int numx, m, j;
};

#endif
```

aHistogram.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "aHistogram.h"
using namespace std;

aHistogram::aHistogram()
{
    numRolls(6);
    numx, m, j = 0;
}

aHistogram::~aHistogram()
{
}

void aHistogram::update(int face)
{
    numRolls.at(face - 1)++;
    return;
}
```

Comment: You declared `numRolls` as a function instead of a data member.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the constructor's initializer list is for:

```
aHistogram::aHistogram(): numRolls(6), numx(0), m(0), j(0) // constructor parameters here
{
    // numRolls(6);
    // numx m, j = 0;
}
```

Also the declaration of your vector is wrong in your class definition:

```
class aHistogram
{
public:
    aHistogram();
    ~aHistogram();
    void update(int face);
    void display(int maxLengthOfLine);
    void clear() const;
    int count(int face);
private:
    // vector<int> numRolls(); // this is declaring a function!
    vector<int> numRolls; // USE THIS!!
    int numx, m, j;
};
```

Comment: Just a little follow up question, what is the right way to access the vector elements in the methods? I get a "left of '.at' must have class/struct/union" every time I try to access it. Sorry noob questions, its my first time using classes and objects and just trying to understand it best I can

Comment: @user3552985 You can use: `numRolls[0] = 2; ... int x = numRolls[5];`. Indexes run `0 - 5` (that's six in total).

Comment: Okay when I try doing it that way it says numRolls is an undeclared identifier. I think the problem may be coming from the header file because I have another error saying "illegal member initialization 'numRolls' is not a base or a member. Its also saying i should have a ";" before the "<" in the vector declaration in the header file.

Comment: @user3552985 Did you `#include <vector>` ?

Comment: Yeah the includes were the first thing I checked, along with any typos and they all seem to be correct. Basically the only thing i changed in the header(from my initial post) were the two "()" after  numRolls in the declaration

Comment: @user3552985 Well your class compiles for me after I made the corrections provided in my answer. You must be doing something else wrong, perhaps you should create another question for it?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try doing that. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user3552985 You know you need to `#include <vector>` in your header right?

Comment: Yeah I have that too. I found the problem, I forgot the namespace in the header. Just put the dunce hat on my head. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

IF the size of the "vector" is fixed, then using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is most certainly a better option, unless of course, you are using an ancient compiler which doesn't support C++11.

Go through the above link on cppreference.com. For most part, it is just like an "old fashioned" array, but it also comes with benefits such as bounds checking (if you use `at()` instead of `operator[]`), ability to iterate through elements (`begin()`, `end()`, etc.), and many other "benefits" of `std::vector`.

Have a look at this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

class aHistogram {
public:
    aHistogram() : numRolls{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} {}

    int count(int face) {
        return numRolls.at(face - 1);
    }

    void update(int face) {
        numRolls.at(face - 1)++;
    }

private:
    array<int, 7> numRolls;
};

int main() {
    aHistogram ah;
    ah.update(1);
    ah.update(2);
    ah.update(1);

    cout << "Count[1]: " << ah.count(1) << " Count[2]: " << ah.count(2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question so should be a comment. Also vector is faster than array for swapping, for example.

Comment: @NeilKirk You are right, however, in this particular question, OP only wants a "vector" of counters, so IMHO, a std::array would be a better option. Please educate me if I am wrong.

Comment: The question requires you use  a vector. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: I don't get it, why does the question **require** you to use a vector? What is the harm caused by using a std::array? Not trying to shoot you down, I want to learn what the issue is. I haven't used C++ for a couple of years, so just trying to brush up on some things I might have forgotten.

Comment: @NeilKirk It seems I misunderstood your point on first reading. Can you please explain to me how vector is faster than array for swapping? It is my first time hearing this statement, I have often heard the opposite, and I would have intuitively thought swapping elements in an array should be better, or at least no worse, than in a vector.

Comment: @Happy Vector does not contain the data directly, but contains a pointer to the data elsewhere. To swap two vectors requires only swapping these pointers (plus a few other bits, such as size information). But the operation is in constant time. Swapping an `std::array` on the other hand, requires swapping every element individually. This is a linear operation.

Comment: Yeah my professor basically thinks a vector is an array on steroids so we're better of using that.

Comment: @NeilKirk thanks, that makes sense. My C++ is a bit rusty, gotta brush up. :)

Comment: @user3552985 vector is more user friendly so it's a good default choice for a new array data structure.

Comment: @user3552985 Sorry to be blunt, but your professor is teaching you nonsense. Also, I am 100% sure your professor has never heard of C++11. Ask him to explain the difference between a C-style array and std::array, and you will find out. Also, you have a choice between learning C++ and learning whatever your professor is teaching you. If you are only learning C++ to pass a test, go with the latter. If you ever plan to write code which others will use, go with the former.